# Import Data in excel using JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have developed a code to scrape data from a website but since I know very little about JSON I could be able to get the output as required shown in below snap:

[image]
However, I am getting all data from the web in the immediate window but want to organize these fields just like an above snap.
Here is my code:

```
Sub FetchTabularInfo()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim col As Variant, icol As New Collection
    Dim csrf As Variant, I&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/1", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll(".table tr a[onclick^='show_ngo_info']")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            icol.Add Split(Split(.Item(I).getAttribute("onclick"), "(""")(1), """)")(0)
        Next I
    End With

    For Each col In icol
        With Http
            .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf", False
            .send
            csrf = .responseText
        End With

        csrf = Split(Replace(Split(csrf, ":")(1), """", ""), "}")(0)

        With Http
            .Open "POST", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info", False
            .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
            .send "id=" & col & "&csrf_test_name=" & csrf
        End With

        Debug.Print Http.responseText
    Next col
End Sub
```

The output in the immediate window is:

[image]

Comment: You’ll to Parse the Json data...

Comment: I don't have an idea dear if you can please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows you how to use a json parser. I use [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After copying the code from there into a standard module called JsonConverter, you need to go VBE>Tools>References>Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

In the json response the `{}` are dictionaries accessed by key; the `[]` are collections accessed by index (or `For Each` over)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FetchTabularInfo()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim col As Variant, icol As New Collection
    Dim csrf As Variant, i&

    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/1", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll(".table tr a[onclick^='show_ngo_info']")
        For i = 0 To .Length - 1
            icol.Add Split(Split(.item(i).getAttribute("onclick"), "(""")(1), """)")(0)
        Next i
    End With

    Dim r As Long, headers(), results(), ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("SrNo", "Name of VGO/NGO", "Address", "City", "State", "Tel", "Mobile", "Web", "Email")
    ReDim results(1 To icol.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    For Each col In icol
        r = r + 1
        With Http
            .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf", False
            .send
            csrf = .responseText
        End With

        csrf = Split(Replace(Split(csrf, ":")(1), """", ""), "}")(0)

        Dim json As Object
        With Http
            .Open "POST", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info", False
            .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
            .send "id=" & col & "&csrf_test_name=" & csrf
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)

            Dim orgName As String, address As String, srNo As Long, city As String
            Dim state As String, tel As String, mobile As String, website As String, email As String

            On Error Resume Next
            orgName = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_orgName")
            address = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_add")
            city = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_city")
            srNo = r '<unsure where this is coming from.
            state = Replace$(json("registeration_info")(1)("StateName"), "amp;", vbNullString)
            tel = IIf(IsNull(json("infor")("0")("Off_phone1")), vbNullString, json("infor")("0")("Off_phone1")) '<unsure where this is coming from. Need a csrf to test with
            mobile = json("infor")("0")("Mobile")
            website = json("infor")("0")("ngo_url")
            email = json("infor")("0")("Email")
            On Error GoTo 0

            Dim arr()
            arr = Array(srNo, orgName, address, city, state, tel, mobile, website, email)
            For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
               results(r, i + 1) = arr(i)
            Next
        End With
    Next col
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am having an issue that only first page data is getting imported on how to import all pages?

Comment: where are other pages coming from?

Comment: Like when you click on link only one page appears, but I need all pages https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/1 after that data from pages after this like this https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/2?  till the last page. But it is only giving results of first page.

Comment: your code only makes an initial request to  "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/1".

Comment: you would need a loop over other urls if doing different pages

Comment: Yes I think I haven't looped, can you guide how to loop through the pages.

Comment: I have posted prior answers on this so will see if I can find any of those links. Otherwise, have a go at adding an outer loop over all urls. You will need to reset r to 0 during the outer loop and write out the array at the end, each time during outer loop, to the next free row. If stuck post back with a new question.

Comment: Will do when I have a moment to have a look.

Comment: Start with having a look through these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+parser+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56445651/how-to-cycle-through-hyperlinks-with-vba-in-an-excel-document/56450041#56450041